# FireBase Rules indexOn Issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to get all emails of users using firebase Query like below

```
private void searchUserByEmail(final String searchText) {  
        DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(Constants.FB_TABLE_USERS).orderByChild(Constants.FB_EMAIL).equalTo(searchText);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
}}
```

And While Searching Any email Which is not in list I am getting a warning message in my console Like

> W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "email"' at table_users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

And My Rules in FireBase is

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read" : "auth != null",
    ".write" : "auth != null",
    "table_users": {
      ".indexOn": ["email"]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Users Table screenshot 
[image]

Comment: try this `".indexOn": "email"`

Comment: @Ali Yes i Tried in that way also but i didn't get any response from firebase

Comment: **"i didn't get any response from firebase"** do you mean the warning not shown ?

Comment: do you mean the warning not shown -->Yes

Comment: then That's it , you make an index on email

Comment: That's Ok the problem here is how I know the response based on that I need to do some functionality in my code. How to Handle it

Comment: I have Used 
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent() it is not comming in both onDataChange and onCancelled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163775/discussion-between-raj-kumar-and-ali).

Comment: I will post the code in the answer

Answer (score 2):

you should remove the brackets from `".indexOn"` value

```
"table_users": {
  ".indexOn": "email"
}
```

---

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue();
            System.out.print(email);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But it is not coming into OnDataChanges Method

Comment: try to pass `"bbb@gmail.com"` to `searchUserByEmail` method , what you get now ?

Comment: Thank You it's working well U saves my time :) 
ForGot this condtion in OnDataChnaged()
                    if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
}